# Soda Date Time with scalajs: type DateTime is not a member of package org.joda

Tags: jodatime, scala.js, playscalajs

I'm trying to use soda date time in my `Play! scalajs` application.

```
Soda date time
```

is imported (without any error) on the client side with

```
"org.mdedetrich" %%% "soda-time" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

But when I try to use it, simply like this:

```
val dateTime = new org.joda.DateTime(new js.Date())
```

I get the following error:

```
type DateTime is not a member of package org.joda
```

I don't see what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the source code of soda-time in GitHub and I think [DateTime](https://github.com/mdedetrich/soda-time/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/org/joda/time/DateTime.scala) is under org.soda.time instead of org.soda

I haven't used soda-time before, but I'm using [scalajs-jsjoda](https://github.com/zoepepper/scalajs-jsjoda) for my cross js and JVM projects.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look when I have some time